# Windows RT / 8 - Clicking on a listview item and passing data between pages

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am working on a WIndows RT application with SQLite. I have a search box that returns results. what I need to do is when the user clicks on the listview item, another screen will display with the details from the selected item. I have the screen open on click but dont know how to pass data between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Add a item click event handler to the listview

```
private void lst_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
     {
        SomeComplexObject item = e.ClickedItem as SomeComplexObject 

        if(item != null)
        {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName), item.ID);
        }
    }
```

considering your object is of a complexType
then in OnNavigatedTo event of

> PageName

you can get the parameter value

hope this helps

for example you can have a

```
public class NavigationParameter
{
 public string CustomerName {get; set;}
 public int CustomerID {get; set;}
}
```

then on ItemClick you can have something like this

```
Customer item = e.ClickedItem as Customer;       
if(item != null)
{
  NavigationParameter p = new NavigationParameter();
  p.CustomerName = item.CustomerName;
  p.CustomerID = item.CustomerID;
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName), p);
 }
```

Comment: I am still new to this, please explain complextype and how would I reference it in the other page?

Comment: what itemsource are you binding to your listview?

Comment: string custSearch = tbxCustSearch.Text.ToString();
            
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbName);
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
            {
                var query = db.Table<Customers>().Where(x => x.customerName.Contains(custSearch));
                listCustomers.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

                db.Dispose();
                db.Close();
            }

Comment: in that case replace SomeComplex type in the code above with "Customers" and you can pass it as a parameter in the Navigate() function in place of item.ID

Comment: Can I use the same function to pass in multiple parameter's?

Comment: you have to create a public class with properties (setters and getters) and access the same on the navigated page